# How to use composer to install part of a git repository?

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I want to require only a sub portion of a git repository (instead of the full thing). The reason i want to do this is because the repository is huge.

In my case the repository is: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api.git and I only want the /php directory.

I have the following package defined in composer:

```
   {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "pubnub",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source" : {
                    "url": "https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                }
            }
    },
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please remember that the best you can do is to retrieve a bare repository (nothing in the working directory), then checkout the files in `php`. You will still end up with all of the history using *git clone* (as I guess that Composer does behind the scenes).

Comment: I am looking for the same behaviour. Any luck?

Comment: I am interested in getting part of repository with composer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the answer to ["Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) Is ["No"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600189/1114274) , and sub directory checkout functionality would be required by composer to satisfy the desired functionality, then I would suggest the best composer could do was checkout the whole thing and then delete what you didnt want.

In short: Not Possible.

The longer answer: 
is that git can do a [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/1114274) so in theory composer could someday support that feature. You can use the [autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) field to only load the section of code you want (ie, not load the whole lib).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the php directory has been moved on its own repository here https://github.com/pubnub/php. That may help for this project, but no idea how to achieve this from main repo and composer...

Comment: Oh, I need another repository which not divided.

Comment: @flavien, thanks for the notes, but it doesnt answer the general question.