# Exclude containing github repo folder on composer install

Tags: php, composer-php

When using composer to install my github repo, the files are contained in a folder that matches the repo name. Is there a way I can stop the files being installed in this folder?

Cheers.

Comment: Where do you want to install them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use composer to install part of a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14486112/1503018)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible. Thanks to those who asked questions :)