# Composer package in a vcs subfolder - how to reference?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created a GIT repo with some URL. Inside that repo is a folder `Release` and that contains a composer package - `composer.json` file, PHP files, etc.

Now, how do I reference this package in another project? Attempt one:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "my/package/Release": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git"
      }
    ]
}
```

Result:

> No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git, could not load a package from it.

Attempt two:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "my/package": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git/Release"
      }
    ]
}
```

Result:

> [RuntimeException]
>    Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git/Result' '/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-my-package.git-Result/'
>
> Cloning into bare repository '/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-my-package.git-Result'...
>    repository does not exist.
>    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>    and the repository exists.

Composer documentation doesn't help either. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use composer to install part of a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486112/how-to-use-composer-to-install-part-of-a-git-repository)